# Static factory method in base class

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, solid, factory-method, open-close

> An increasingly popular definition of factory method is: a static
>   method of a class that returns an object of that class' type. But
>   unlike a constructor, the actual object it returns might be an
>   instance of a subclass.
>   [image]

From : https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method

Doesn't it violate OCP?

I have also seen this in production code.

What would be the correct implementation?

I can think of a separate Creator class with static method, which returns subclass objects.
My proposed solution is clearly not abstract factory as it doesn't create families of products, also it doesn't fit any of the GoF creational pattern. So I am skeptical about my solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [*Open/Close Principe (OCP)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle):

> Software entities (classes, modules, functions, etc.) should be open
>   for extension, but closed for modification.

Let's examine your static factory architecture under this perspective:

- Imagine that we want to **extend** our design horizontally with a subclass `ProductThree`.  How could the `makeProduct()` return an object that could be one of the subclass without knowing the constructor of the subclasses ?  I can think of two approaches:

  - You might have to change the method if it is implemented as a huge `switch` or chained `if`. This would infringe OCP.
  - You could think of a self registration mechanism that decouples `Product` from its subclasses (e.g. using a map / [associative container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_containers) mapping a class name / identifier with a class maker method- [Java example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18236369/3723423)). This would meet extensibility requirement and remain compliant with OCP.
- Imagine that we want to **extend** our design vertically, by specializing `ProductOne` into `ProductOneA` and `ProductOneB`. To achieve this, you could not rely on sub class constructors in `makeProduct()`.  You would have to use a `makeProductOne()`.  This requires that the self registration is designed so to enable cascading through the hierachy. Although this could be challenging, it doesn't seem impossible.
- Suppose that we could find a way to implement the self-registration requirement in the design.  In this case you could completely seal the factory method, in compliance with OCP.

In conclusion, the concept of the static factory is compliant with OCP.  Of course, specific implementation might infringe OCP, but only if they wouldn't  take into consideration the additional requirements I mentioned above.

Note that using a factory class is a cleaner approach : it enforces [separation of concerns](https://effectivesoftwaredesign.com/2012/02/05/separation-of-concerns/) (i.e. avoid that the factory knows about internals of the Product).  But with regard to OCP, using a static method as explained above is an acceptable alternative.

I can't tell for other languages, but Andrei Alexandrescu demonstrated the implementation of a factory method in ["*Modern C++ design - Generic Programming and design patterns applied*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_C%2B%2B_Design).  It's full OCP using a map and registering/unregistering functions.  The only difficulty he mentions it the type identifier that has to be provided to the factory.  Of course, an `enum` would be an OCP issue, but he explored several alternatives using RTTI or a unique ID generator to circumvent this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you don't see static factory methods listed in the GoF book is because this pattern doesn't use polymorphism in any interesting way. Your diagram suggests this, but most languages do not support the structure it shows. Specifically, a static method cannot also be virtual. There is no instance object to dispatch on. It is not possible to override a static method in the way you could override an instance method (some languages have class methods though, where we can dispatch on the class object). While the GoF book is only concerned about showcasing object-oriented patterns, static factory methods are still a common pattern in many languages.

What the page you linked to describes are two distinct patterns.

First we have the common pattern that rather than exposing a constructor of our class, we provide a static method. Many languages allow us to define multiple constructors and resolves them through method overloading, but static methods can have different names which is far more programmer-friendly. The linked page uses `Color` objects as an example. `new Color(float, float, float)` might be obvious, but can't be overloaded with different color models (RGB vs. HSV). Static methods can disambiguate through the name: `Color::make_rgb(float, float, float)` versus `Color::make_hsv(float, float, float)`. This is about good API design, but has nothing to do with object orientation.

Using (static) factory methods also offers us more freedom in the implementation. We could map the HSV colors to RGB internally. Or `Color` could be abstract and used different subclasses for each color space, without exposing this difference to the user. This implementation detail is entirely encapsulated:

```java
public static Color makeRGB(float r, float g, float b) {
  return new ColorRGB(r, g, b);
}

public static Color makeHSV(float h, float s, float v) {
  return new ColorHSV(h, s, v);
}
```

In my experience, such methods make code less ambiguous and make an API more approachable and maintainable. In C++, there's the additional benefit that static methods can use template argument deduction, whereas class template parameters have to be provided explicitly in a constructor call.

Factory methods have another interesting feature: We can decide in our code which concrete type to instantiate. I have used this in some parsers:

```java
Expression makeBinaryExpression(Expression left, String operator, Expression right) {
  if (operator == "+") return new Addition(left, right);
  if (operator == "-") return new Subtraction(left, right);
  if (operator == "*") return new Multiplication(left, right);
  if (operator == "/") return new Division(left, right);
  throw new ParseException("Expected +, -, *, /, but got " + operator);
}
```

You are right that such static methods pose an extensibility problem. How could I add the CMYK color model to the `Color` class? I can't, without editing the `Color` class, or replacing it with a different but compatible class (by changing imports, or by C++ templates). If extensibility is required, the API should be made virtual – we'll come back to that in a minute.

However, not all code needs to be polymorphic. Especially if the behaviour is “pure” and doesn't interact with any outside state and when the behaviour is nor likely to change, non-virtual methods still have a place.

Also, the open-closed principle is only relevant when you can't change the source and release a new version. This is the case with published APIs where the publisher and consumer are in different organizations. In such a case, there must be a clear API and this interface must be carefully designed to allow consumers to adapt it to their needs – often by requiring dependency injection and consistently expressing the API in terms of user-implementable interfaces. But if the code is only used within the same project, the OCP is not as relevant (relying on interfaces can still make it easier to refactor, though).

Now let's get back to polymorphism. The GoF book does list the Factory Method Pattern and likens it to a “virtual constructor”. The whole point here is that the factory method is virtual and overrideable. This of course means that a factory method on the `Product` class is useless, since we would need to have an existing `Product` in order to create it. Instead, there is a different `Creator` class. The factory method is then an example of the Template Method Pattern which can be overridden by Creator-subclasses to provide a specific Product-subclass. The Abstract Factory Pattern is an example of a creator with multiple related factory methods.

Occasionally, factory methods are also used as a dependency injection mechanism. The base class defines some template methods to construct the dependencies, which can then be changed through subclassing. However, my experience shows that using small Strategy objects to open up dependency construction is a more flexible and simpler approach rather than requiring the whole target class to be inherited.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!!

I think there was some confusion in last paragraph of my question. I have edited it to make my intention more clear.

Comment: @amon Great post, just coming across this.  I'd like to add, and to also ask your opinion - with static factory methods, I am able to maintain extensibility using move semantics (C++11). So a derived class can call the base class static method, and as long as move constructors are provided by the base class, can use the return value from that static method to initialize it's base class. Is this not an acceptable solution - assuming by design your stack of classes all implement static methods/move constructors?

Comment: @user3814483 Correct, with C++11 it's OK if a base class only exposes public default/copy/move constructors as appropriate, and only offers factory methods for other tasks. The subclass would then have a constructor like `SubClass() : BaseClass(BaseClass::some_factory()) {}`. Compilers are also generally free to do copy elision. However, this C++ trivia does not address extensibility concerns: no amount of move constructors will cause a `makeProduct()` function start returning a new `ProductThree`.

Comment: @amon I agree with your point re:`makeProduct()` and the question posed by the OP. I took the extensibility concerns to mean subclassing... hence sanity-checking.